# Thread handling in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code.. When i am executing this code, all the 5 thread windows are displaying at the same time. But I want to execute a single thread with some value in each iteration. More than two threads should not be executed at a time..
The second thread(key=1) should start only after the completion of the first thread(key=0), and third thread(key=2) only after the completion of the second thread, and so on. Please help..
How can deal with this problem.

```
for (long key = 0; key < 5; key++)
{                                                      
                    var processingThread = new Thread(() => DoDataSetup(key));                         
                    _progress = new ProgressReport(processingThread);
                    _progress.Show();
                    _progress.FormClosed += delegate(object delSender, FormClosedEventArgs args)
                    {
                        this.Enabled = true;
                    };

                    this.Enable    d = false;

                    processingThread.Start();                                                          
                }
```

Comment: Why multithreading in this case?

Comment: You could use semaphore to let only 2 threads to work at same time.

Comment: I want to show all the 5 progress windows at the end. That's why i want 2 create 5 threads.. is there any other way?

Answer (score -1):

First of all it is better to use [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) for Task creation, but I suggest you to create threads with use of [Task.Run(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx). For allowing to enter only a limited number of threads you could use the [Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194745(v=vs.110).aspx) class, or you use the [BatchBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx) of the TPL-API

```
//with semaphore
var semaphore = new Semaphore(0,2);
for(long key = 0; key < 5; key++)
{
    semaphore.WaitOne();

    ProcessWorking(key);

    semaphore.Release();
}

public void ProcessWorking(long key)
{
    var processingThread = new Thread(() => DoDataSetup(key));                         
    _progress = new ProgressReport(processingThread);
    _progress.Show();
    _progress.FormClosed += delegate(object delSender, FormClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.Enabled = true;
    };

    this.Enabled = false;
    processingThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: But the ProgressReport() accepts and assign thread type.. so how should it modify if i am using _progress = new ProgressReport(processingTask);?

 public ProgressReport(Thread processingThread)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _processingThread = processingThread;
           }

Comment: You can change the ProgressReport's parameter to Task. Why do you need to have a reference to the calling thread?

Comment: Ok, I will modify the code to include Seamaphore only

Comment: but in this case, how can i get the key value in DoDataSetup(key)??